# Trouble with speeding up functions with numba JIT

Tags: python, numpy, jit, numba

I am new to numba's jit. For a personal project, I need to speed up functions that are similar to what will be shown below, though different for the purpose of writing standalone examples.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, autojit, double, float64, float32, void

def f(n):
    k=0.
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            k+= i+j

def f_with_return(n):
    k=0.
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            k+= i+j
    return k

def f_with_arange(n):
    k=0.
    for i in np.arange(n):
        for j in np.arange(n):
            k+= i+j

def f_with_arange_and_return(n):
    k=0.
    for i in np.arange(n):
        for j in np.arange(n):
            k+= i+j  


#jit decorators
jit_f = jit(void(int32))(f)
jit_f_with_return = jit(int32(int32))(f_with_return)
jit_f_with_arange = jit(void(double))(f_with_arange)
jit_f_with_arange_and_return = jit(double(double))(f_with_arange_and_return)
```

And the benchmarks:

```
%timeit f(1000)
%timeit jit_f(1000)
```

10 loops, best of 3: 73.9 ms per loop / 1000000 loops, best of 3: 212 ns per loop

```
%timeit f_with_return(1000)
%timeit jit_f_with_return(1000)
```

10 loops, best of 3: 74.9 ms per loop / 1000000 loops, best of 3: 220 ns per loop

**I don't understand these two:**

```
%timeit f_with_arange(1000.0)
%timeit jit_f_with_arange(1000.0)
```

10 loops, best of 3: 175 ms per loop / 1 loops, best of 3: 167 ms per loop

```
%timeit f_with_arange_with_return(1000.0)
%timeit jit_f_with_arange_with_return(1000.0)
```

10 loops, best of 3: 174 ms per loop / 1 loops, best of 3: 172 ms per loop

I think I'm not giving the jit function the correct types for the output and input ? Just because the for loop is now running over a numpy.arange, and not a simple range anymore, I cannot get jit to make it faster. What is the issue here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply, numba doesn't know how to convert `np.arange` into a low level native loop, so it defaults to the object layer which is much slower and usually the same speed as pure python.

A nice trick is to pass the `nopython=True` keyword argument to `jit` to see if it can compile everything without resorting to the object mode:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def f_with_return(n):
    k=0.
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            k+= i+j
    return k

jit_f_with_return = nb.jit()(f_with_return)
jit_f_with_return_nopython = nb.jit(nopython=True)(f_with_return)

%timeit f_with_return(1000)
%timeit jit_f_with_return(1000)
%timeit jit_f_with_return_nopython(1000)
```

The last two are the same speed on my machine and much faster than the un-jitted code. The two examples that you had questions about will raise an error with `nopython=True` since it can't compile `np.arange` at this point.

See the following for more details:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/user/troubleshoot.html#the-compiled-code-is-too-slow

and for a list of supported numpy features with indications of what is and is not supported in `nopython` mode:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/reference/numpysupported.html